# цикл js, работа с данными

Tags: javascript

```
    $.each($('#dual .dualclass'), function(index,value) {
        allow_countries.forEach(function (element, index) {
            if(element['id'] == value['value']) {
                $(value).attr('selected', true);
            }
        });
    });
```

как в цикле перед присвоением атрибута удалить у всех абсолютно других совпадений до начала цикла этот самы атрибут selected?

Answer (score 2):

Первая строчка, то, что тебе нужно. Пиши только в следующий раз грамотнее. Возможно это $('#dual .dualclass') нужно заменить на что-то другое в твоем контексте, но суть та же.

```
$('#dual .dualclass').attr('selected',false);

$.each($('#dual .dualclass'), function(index,value) {
  allow_countries.forEach(function (element, index) {
     if(element['id'] == value['value']) {
        $(value).attr('selected', true);
     }
  });
});
```